# MergeSort using MultiThread

Tags: c++, multithreading, mergesort

I'm using multithreading for mergesort

```
void mergeSort(std::vector<int>& vec,int s,int e){
    if(s>=e)
        return;
    int mid=(s+e)/2;
    std::thread t1(std::bind(mergeSort,std::ref(vec),s,mid));
    std::thread t2(std::bind(mergeSort,std::ref(vec),mid+1,e));
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    merge(vec,s,mid,e);
}
```

If my dataset is very large then error might be thrown since the amount of threads that can created is finite .
Is there a way to handle such a case

Comment: sorry but I really don't understand the question; what is the link between the number of thread and the error in your code? (that said, you shoudl use std::async instead of threads)

Comment: Sure: 1) Create a fixed number of threads (_n_; typically, the same as the nubmer of cores), 2) split the sequence into _n_ parts of equal length, 3) merge-sort each part with a single thread independently, 4) use _k_-way multi-threaded merge to merge those sorted parts together. The last step is the most tricky one to implement.

Comment: @OznOg the function recursively spawns threads and the ones spawned first join last. At some point you hit a limit

Comment: There's no error in my code, if i'm using a large dataset then number of threads created will increase right? since the function is being recursively called which at a point may throw exception

Comment: @DanielLangr - after using n threads to sort n sub-arrays, it would be faster to merge even and odd sub-arrays using n/2 threads, and then again using n/4 threads, and/or then a single thread to merge the final two sub-arrays. [Example code using 4 Windows native threads](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/148025)  .

Comment: You need a cut-off. Note that you can OpenMP for such a computation (or a similar tool). It can be easier/simpler to do and more efficient (due to a better thread management and tasks for example). OpenMP also help for doing a cut-off. Such an example is provided in the standard OpenMP examples.

Comment: If you have large data set, you need to use an out-of-box library, like inteltbb, ` , by the way, `std::sort` also have a multiple threading version since c++17

Comment: @rcgldr Why do you think it would be faster? There will be many cores idle in this solution. Have you compared it with a parallel k-way merge? Such as the one from libstdc++ parallel mode: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/parallel/multiway_merge.h, which is very efficient?

Comment: @rcgldr BTW, in the link you provided, you tried your solution only on a 4-core CPU. Try to compare it with other parallel merge sort implementations on a system with much more core, such as 20+.

Comment: @DanielLangr - at some point it will become memory bound. Part of this will depend on how much cache is dedicated to each core. On my systems, it's the 32K L1 cache and 256K L2 cache. The 8 MB cache is shared between all 4 cores. In the link I provided, I noted only a modest gain when going from 4 to 8 threads on a 4 core system.